# Using revgeocode function in a FOR loop. Help required

Tags: r, loops

My problem is as detailed below:

My input data is of the format as given in the small example below:

```
USERID  LONGITUDE   LATITUDE 
1            -8.79659           55.879554 
2           -6.874743           56.87896 
3           -3.874743           58.87896 
4          -10.874743           80.87896
```

I have used the follwoing code to reverse geocode the latitiude and longitude

```
dset <- as.data.frame(dataset[,2:3]) 
dset <- na.omit(dset) 

library (ggmap) 
location <- dset 
nrow(location) 

locaddr <- matrix(0,nrow(location),1) 
location <- as.matrix(location) 
for (i in 1:nrow(location)) 
{ 


   locaddr[i,] <- revgeocode(location[i,], output = c("address"), messaging = FALSE, sensor = FALSE, override_limit = FALSE)



}
```

Now certain longitude-latitude return NA from Google Maps API. But when this happens the for loop is terminated for some reason. I would like to circumvent this and continue processing for the remaining data points. One idea I had was the following pseudocode:

```
if i = nrow(location) 
continue 
else 
repeat revgeocode for loop here 
end-for 
end-if.
```

Kindly advise how this can be done or if there is a better way to do this.

Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use a `for-loop` here. I recommand you to use `lapply` to avoid  side effect, and pre-allocate problems:

```
    locaddr <- lapply(seq(nrow(location)), function(i){ 
           revgeocode(location[i,], 
                         output = c("address"), 
                         messaging = FALSE, 
                         sensor = FALSE, 
                         override_limit = FALSE)
              })
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer... I will implement it and test it out. I am new to R and your guidance is most appreciated.