# Applying revgeocode to a list of longitude-latitude coordinates

Tags: r, google-maps, loops, ggmap

I'm trying to get the Zip codes of a (long) list of Longitude Latitude coordinates by using the revgeodcode function in the ggmap library.

My question & data are the same as here: [Using revgeocode function in a FOR loop. Help required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17505147/using-revgeocode-function-in-a-for-loop-help-required/17505224#17505224) but the accepted answer does not work for me.

My data (.csv):

```
ID,      Longitude,      Latitude
311175,  41.298437,      -72.929179
292058,  41.936943,      -87.669838
12979,   37.580956,      -77.471439
```

I follow the same steps:

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose())
dset <- as.data.frame(data[,2:3])
location = dset
locaddr <- lapply(seq(nrow(location)), function(i){
               revgeocode(location[i,],
               output = c("address"),
               messaging = FALSE,
               sensor = FALSE,
               override_limit = FALSE)
               })
```

... and get the error message: "Error: is.numeric(location) && length(location) == 2 is not TRUE"
Specifically, is.numeric(location) is FALSE, which seems strange because I can multiply by 2 and get the expected answer.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If the answer didn't work why did you accept it? You should post this as a comment to the answer.

Comment: I didn't accept it. the op did.

Comment: Sorry, I though you were the OP there as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are lots of things wrong here.

First, you have latitude and longitude reversed. All the locations in your dataset, as specified, are in Antarctica.

Second, `revgeocode(...)` expects a numeric vector of length 2 containing the longitude and latitude in that order. You are passing a `data.frame` object (this is the reason for the error), and as per (1) it's in the wrong order.

Third, `revgeocode(...)` uses the google maps api, which limits you to 2500 queries a day. So if you really do have a large dataset, good luck with that.

This code works with your sample:

```
data <- read.csv(text="ID,      Longitude,      Latitude
311175,  41.298437,      -72.929179
292058,  41.936943,      -87.669838
12979,   37.580956,      -77.471439")

library(ggmap)
result <- do.call(rbind,
                  lapply(1:nrow(data),
                         function(i)revgeocode(as.numeric(data[i,3:2]))))
data <- cbind(data,result)
data
#       ID Longitude  Latitude                                           result
# 1 311175  41.29844 -72.92918 16 Church Street South, New Haven, CT 06519, USA
# 2 292058  41.93694 -87.66984  1632 West Nelson Street, Chicago, IL 60657, USA
# 3  12979  37.58096 -77.47144    2077-2199 Seddon Way, Richmond, VA 23230, USA
```

This extracts the zipcodes:

```
library(stringr)
data$zipcode <- substr(str_extract(data$result," [0-9]{5}, .+"),2,6)
data[,-4]
#       ID Longitude  Latitude zipcode
# 1 311175  41.29844 -72.92918   06519
# 2 292058  41.93694 -87.66984   60657
# 3  12979  37.58096 -77.47144   23230
```

Comment: Thanks very much for taking the time to help. I've seen that it works and have noted your comments.

Answer (score 2):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API with a valid API key. So if your data is greater than 2,500 items you can pay for an API key, and then use `googleway::google_reverse_geocode()`

For example

```
data <- read.csv(text="ID,      Longitude,      Latitude
311175,  41.298437,      -72.929179
292058,  41.936943,      -87.669838
12979,   37.580956,      -77.471439")

library(googleway)

key <- "your_api_key"

res <- apply(data, 1, function(x){
  google_reverse_geocode(location = c(x["Latitude"], x["Longitude"]),
                         key = key)
})

## Everything contained in 'res' is all the data returnd from Google Maps API
## for example, the geometry section of the first lat/lon coordiantes

res[[1]]$results$geometry
bounds.northeast.lat bounds.northeast.lng bounds.southwest.lat bounds.southwest.lng location.lat location.lng
1            -61.04904                  180                  -90                 -180    -75.25097    -0.071389
location_type viewport.northeast.lat viewport.northeast.lng viewport.southwest.lat viewport.southwest.lng
1   APPROXIMATE              -61.04904                    180                    -90                   -180
```

Comment: I pretty much copied this, but get the following error: "Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default"

Comment: @AgustínIndaco - I just copied and pasted this exact code and did not receive an error. Have you changed something else in the code?

Answer (score -2):

To extract the zip code just write down:

```
>data$postal_code
```