# How to display google map directions given latitude and longitude information in r

Tags: r, google-maps, ggmap, rgooglemaps

I have with me the latitude and logitude information for few locations. Here is a sample:

```
lat<-c(17.48693,17.49222,17.51965,17.49359,17.49284,17.47077)
long<-c(78.38945,78.39643,78.37835,78.40079,78.40686,78.35874)
```

I want to plot these locations in some order(say lat-long combination of first elements in the above vectors will be the starting point and i need to travel in the same order till last location) with google map directions in R. Upon some search I found that there is a google map api from which i can get google map screenshot of specified locations and on top of it we need to plot lines to connect them. But what I need is google map driving directions to connect the locations (not ggplot lines).
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically comes down to creating a `route_df` and then plotting the results as `geom_path`. For example, for a single route, you could do something like this:

```
library(ggmap)

route_df <- route(from = "Hyderabad, Telangana 500085, India",
                  to = "Kukatpally, Hyderabad, Telangana 500072, India",
                  structure = "route")

my_map <- get_map("Hyderabad, Telangana 500085, India", zoom = 13)

ggmap(my_map) +
  geom_path(aes(x = lon, y = lat), color = "red", size = 1.5,
            data = route_df, lineend = "round")
```

[image: Map with route]

So you could probably approach this by generating each of the from-to routes and `rbind`-ing all of the results into one large `route_df` and plotting the final results. It's easier for others to help you if you make an attempt and show where (*with code*) you are getting stuck. You may want to edit your original question or possibly submit a new one after you show what you have tried.

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22911642/2572423) with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22919546/2572423) should prove helpful.

Answer (score 8):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API with a valid API key.

You can use the function `google_directions()` to get the directions, including waypoints, route steps, legs, distances, times, etc.

For example

```
library(googleway)

## using a valid Google Maps API key
key <- "your_api_key"

## Using the first and last coordinates as the origin/destination
origin <- c(17.48693, 78.38945)
destination <- c(17.47077, 78.35874)

## and the coordinates in between as waypoints
waypoints <- list(via = c(17.49222, 78.39643),
                  via = c(17.51965, 78.37835),
                  via = c(17.49359, 78.40079),
                  via = c(17.49284, 78.40686))
## use 'stop' in place of 'via' for stopovers

## get the directions from Google Maps API
res <- google_directions(origin = origin,
                         destination = destination,
                         waypoints = waypoints,
                         key = key)  ## include simplify = F to return data as JSON
```

The result is all the data received from Google Maps

```
## see the structure
# str(res)
```

The line that you see on Google Maps is contained in

```
res$routes$overview_polyline$points
# [1] "slviBqmm}MSLiA{B^wAj@sB}Ac@...
```

Which is an encoded polyline.

To get the lat/lon from this use the function `decode_pl()`

```
df_polyline <- decode_pl(res$routes$overview_polyline$points)
head(df_polyline)
#        lat      lon
# 1 17.48698 78.38953
# 2 17.48708 78.38946
# 3 17.48745 78.39008
# 4 17.48729 78.39052
# 5 17.48707 78.39110
# 6 17.48754 78.39128
```

Which of course you can then plot as you wish

```
library(leaflet)

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data = df_polyline, lat = ~lat, lng = ~lon)
```

[image]

---

#### Edit 2017-07-21

As of `googleway` 2.0 you can plot the polyline in a Google Map, either using the decoded coordinates as before, or by using the polyline directly

```
google_map(key = key) %>%
    add_polylines(data = data.frame(polyline = res$routes$overview_polyline$points), 
                                polyline = "polyline")
```

[image]

Comment: Question tags are meant to capture the contents of the question; please stop adding tags related to your library to question that do not ask about your library. [tag:googleway] only belongs on questions that are specifically about that library.

Comment: @josliber - I interpreted this meta post - [tagging a question based on its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252079/5977215) to mean it was acceptable to do so.

Comment: See for instance http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers#comment6308_252080 on that post -- please only tag a library/tool if it's being asked about in the question.

Comment: @josliber - is it also policy to declare you are the author of a package if you write it as an answer? If so, should I be flagging answers that violate said policy?

Comment: Yes, if you recommend your own package then you need to disclose that you are the author (as you did on this answer). Please do flag answers that violate this policy.

Comment: @josliber ok - and lastly; if a question explicitely asks about a specific package, then does the author need to identify themselves? I ask because I know a lot of `R` package authors who answer questions without identifying themselves?

Comment: Nobody should be answering package recommendation questions period -- they should be closed because they are asking for package recommendations. Beyond that, the general rule is: if somebody asks about package X, then package X's maintainer can answer without disclosing affiliation (they are not promoting). If somebody asks a question that does not mention package X and package X's maintainer suggests package X to solve it, they need to disclose affiliation and make sure that they are not doing this for a high percentage of their answers.

Comment: @josliber "... answering package recommendation questions ... " - sorry, that wasn't the intent of my question. However, the rest of your comment answered it nicely :). I'll go away now...

Comment: Thank you, though i didn't use your google way, knowing that leaflet can give a less static map compared to ggmap is very helpful

Comment: @SymbolixAU Is it possible to implement  the same without specifying the `Origin` and `destination` value?. I would like to implement  `add_polylines` to my maps where I will not be having the values of `origin` and `destination` instead I will be having set of `lat` and `Lon`.